# Retrieving a formula in a text cell

Tags: notebooks, traditional-form

I was entering a formula in a text cell and all was going well until I selected the formula and pressed ctrl-'/' and then the formula got converted to this:

```
Subscript[D, Subscript[\[Omega], i]] (Subscript[\[Omega], m]) = 
(Subscript[G, 1] (Subscript[\[Omega], i], Subscript[\[Omega], m]) | 
Subscript[\[Omega], i] . Subscript[\[Omega], m] | 
D (Subscript[\[Omega], m]))/(| 
Subscript[\[Omega], i] . Subscript[\[Omega], g] |)
```

Undo did not return my equation back.

Is there a way to return the equation to its traditional form when in a text cell?

Comment: CTRL + / is the shortcut for a fraction, so I don't really know why it ruined your formula. Have you tried playing with the Cell -> Convert To menu options?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried many things but none worked. I don't think I explicitly tied 'Cell -> Convert To' though. But eventually I learned about Ctrl + '(' and then rewrote the formula.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start from the beginning so that you have to read through my answer :)

When you have a text-cell and start to write a formula, Mathematica will insert another *inline cell* as soon as you use subscript, superscript, and other things. This is indicated by a yellowish markup of the inline cell, when your cursor is inside

[image: img]

As you learned, you can trigger this yourself when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>. This helps greatly when your formula doesn't require superscript and you want consistent formatting even when you have only a single letter as "formula".

If you want to see what happens under the hood, you can always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see the cell expression. For this simple example for instance

[image: img]

we get the following cell expression

```
Cell[TextData[{
 "This function ",
 Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox["D", TraditionalForm]],
  FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]
}], "Text"]
```

If you look through this, you see there is a `Cell` inside your outer `Cell` and while your outer cell is `"Text"`, your inner cell is formatted in `TraditionalForm`. Important is, that this inner cell is really nothing more than a cell that we simply call *Inline Cell* but can otherwise be manipulated or converted.

If you recreate my first example and move the cursor inside the formula, please go to the menu *Cell* -> *Convert To*. You should see two things:

1. The Traditional Form entry is checked
2. The shortcut for InputForm is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

That being said, here is my CSI Miami crime scene analysis: You were writing your formula and out of the blue, you probably wanted to make something italic. You though, the shortcut for italic is *always* something with "I" and you were trying different combinations. That's when you hit the shortcut for converting the inline cell into `InputForm` and the following happened

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The good thing is, this can easily be reverted by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or *Cell* -> *Convert To* -> *Traditional Form*. The bad thing is, I'm obvoisly too late :)

I hope this still helps you in future and lets you understand what happened.